# History behind the Kamakhya Temple?

Tags: history, temple

Do you know history behind the Kamakhya Temple located in Guwahati Assam, why it is called the Famous Shakti Peeth ?

Answer (score 1):

> Once goddess Sati struggled with her husband Lord Shiva to present in the great yagna, organized by her father. There father of Sati Daksha insulted lord Shiva, knowing that sati got angered and accepted it as her shame. The sati Jumped in the advanced fire of yagna and killed herself.
>
> When lord Shiva got to know about the incident that his wife committed suicide, he gets furious with rage. Placing the body of dead sati on his shoulders, he started doing Tandav, a dance of destruction. To calm down Shiva, lord Vishnu cut the body of sati in 108 parts by his Chakra, where the body parts of Sati fell is known as Shakti Peeth.
>
> There are 51 Shakti peeth in India, where the body parts of Sati fell.
>
> Kamakhya Devi is also one of the Shakti Peeth where Vagina and womb of sati fell, so this place got recognition as kamakhya Devi temple.

[Reference](http://kamakhyasindoor.com/about-kamakhya-devi/)